# What's a good lens for my Canon G7?

Tags: lens, canon, image-quality, canon-g11

I'm not a professional photographer, but I use my camera on a regular basis to photograph my familiy and activities I attend.  I own a Canon G7 (older version of the G11) and instead of upgrading to a full-on (D)SLR camera, I've heard that getting a new lens for it would help with picture quality immensely.  So what is a decent general-use lens (or a few common single-purpose lenses) that that will improve the quality of my photos?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can in fact get additional lenses for the Canon G7.  More precisely they are called "**converters**".  The "gotcha" is that they only sit on top of your existing fixed lens that is built into the G7.  The **Canon WC-DC58B** is one option that will convert all focal lengths to .75 of the original focal length.  Another option is the **Canon TC-DC58C** Teleconverter which will give you 2x the focal length of the original lens.

So in fact you aren't going to get higher picture quality, rather you have the ability to shoot at different focal lengths by using these lens converters.  Common knowledge suggests that this will only **multiply any flaws your current built in fixed lens has**.

If you are unsatisfied with the G7's quality of the photos, you aren't going to be able to switch to a different lens or modify it with one of the above converters to get a higher quality.  A DSLR might be the path you want to follow.

Comment: Actually, to be accurate, what you're describing is a *converter* or a *lens modifier*, not a *lens*. The distinction is that a lens projects light directly onto a medium (sensor, film, etc.), whereas a lens modifier alters the characteristics of an existing lens. Not to take away from what you've written, I just wanted to make sure we were using the correct terms so we're not confusing people...

Comment: Yea, I suppose that I agree.  B&H calls it a lens, so I figured I was safe :-)  I do see that Canon calls it a converter.

Comment: This is good information.  I was hoping to avoid the cost of a DSLR camera, but that might be what I have to do.

Comment: @PHLAK: Another option is buying a better P&S camera. Most likely *much* cheaper than a good DSLR + good lenses...

Comment: @Juka Any recommendations on a good P&S then?

Answer (score 2):

You are right that a new lens can improve image quality considerably.

Unfortunately, the **G7 is a fixed-lens camera and therefore you cannot get a new lens for it**. Sadly I have seen vendors say the contrary to make people buy it but it is a lie.

Answer (score 1):

"Improving the quality of photos" is a difficult goal without knowing what you think is wrong with your shots.

However, you can get a lens adapter, from [LensMate](http://www.lensmateonline.com/store/g9.php), for instance.

Or, you can use [CHDK](http://chdk.wikia.com/wiki/CHDK) and get more control over your firmware.  Maybe you feel like your photos can be improved by adding things like timelapse shots?

Comment: Adapters have no chance of improving image quality since more glass is prone to adding its own layer of aberrations, distortions, flare and softness.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by 'improving image quality'.  If he wants to take a wide angle image, then it could be considered an improvement to add that piece of glass if it gives him that capability.